# Error Installing opencv-python on linux /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia

I have been following this tutorial to install opencv and python:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/#comment-441393

The only difference is that I am trying to install opencv 3.3.1 instead of 3.0.0

I'm running on a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 an i7 and NVIDIA GTX950M

The problem is that when I execute the command `ldconfig`

```
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

I get the following message:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to the problem:

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/900285/libegl-so-1-is-not-a-symbolic-link @muru @Gerard Tromp

> The following is an easy-to-use version of Noisy_Botnet's solution. It
>   facilitates repeating the process for any update.

Create a shell script, i.e., paste the code bellow a text file, and save it with the .sh extension.
Change the executing permissions of the file i.e., go to the location of the file in the terminal and execute the following command $`sudo chmod 744 nameofthefieleyoucreated.sh`
execute the following command $`sudo ./nameofthefileyoucreated.sh`

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# find the file in /usr/lib
LIBEGL=`find /usr/lib/nvidia* -name libEGL.so.\* | egrep "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$"`
LIBEGL_LINK=`echo $LIBEGL | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$/1/'`
printf "\n\nThe following commands will be executed:\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n"
printf "mv $LIBEGL_LINK ${LIBEGL_LINK}.orig\nln -s $LIBEGL $LIBEGL_LINK\n\n"
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to perform these commands?  " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) mv $LIBEGL_LINK ${LIBEGL_LINK}.orig; ln -s $LIBEGL $LIBEGL_LINK ; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done

# find the file in /usr/lib32
LIBEGL=`find /usr/lib32/nvidia* -name libEGL.so.\* | egrep "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$"`
LIBEGL_LINK=`echo $LIBEGL | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*$/1/'`
printf "\n\nThe following commands will be executed:\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n"
printf "mv $LIBEGL_LINK ${LIBEGL_LINK}.orig\nln -s $LIBEGL $LIBEGL_LINK\n\n"
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to perform these commands?  " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) mv $LIBEGL_LINK ${LIBEGL_LINK}.orig; ln -s $LIBEGL $LIBEGL_LINK ; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```